# Conditional expected value of coin flips

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose you flip four coins and you're guaranteed that at least 2 are heads. What is the expected value of the number of heads? I have the following calculation.

\begin{align}
& \operatorname E\left[ X \mid X \geq 2\right] \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{n = 2}^4 nP [X=n\mid X \geq 2] \\[8pt]
= {} & 2 \cdot \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{11} + 3 \cdot \frac{4}{11} + 4 \cdot \frac{1}{11} \\[8pt]
= {} & 2.5454.
\end{align}

Is this calculation correct? Specifically is the use of the conditional probability distribution in the first step correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X\mid X\geqslant 2] &= \frac{\mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_{\{X\geqslant 2\}}]}{\mathbb P(X\geqslant 2)}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{k=2}^4 k\binom 4k 2^{-4}}{\sum_{k=2}^4\binom 4k 2^{-4}}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{k=2}^4 k\binom 4k}{\sum_{k=2}^4\binom 4k}\\
&= \frac{28}{11}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The argument given in the question is correct. (If I were writing it to be read by someone who doesn't know how to do this until they read what I wrote, I would probably say more than what you've said.)